# How to git diff from an earlier version without some of the intermediate additions?

Tags: git, diff, patch

I'm working on an addition to a project that is loosely based on another patch to the same project. I started by cloning the repository (**A**). I then applied the patch I wanted use as "inspiration" for my additions (**B**). I made a branch in preparation for my changes (**C**) and then added the new code (**D**).

```
A-----B
       \
        \
         C-----D
```

I want my new additions to be separate from the "inspiration" patch. How can I now generate a patch file (ie, git diff) that does not include the "inspiration" patch (B or C)? The patches will each essentially represent a plugin with a unique use case, so the process for getting each rolled into the project will be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rebase your change to be based on `A` instead of `C`.

```
git rebase --onto A C
```

Comment: I hadn't used the --onto option for rebase yet. The documentation was a bit confusing. Thinking of it this way helped... git rebase --onto destination removethis playthisback

Answer (score 1):

If **D** doesn't depend on **B** or **C**, you should just be able to generate a patch from **C**->**D** and get exactly what you want:

```
git format-patch C..D
```

Comment: The patch generated that way almost works, except for one file where I added to an array that defines the plugins and the context lines aren't matching up, when I try to "git apply" it to a fresh clone of A.

Comment: So then fix those conflicts, and regenerate the patch!